# Pdf generado por rotativa se corta en la parte final libwkhtmltox Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, rotativa

estoy usando la libreria libwkhtmltox https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf
Se genera apartir de un html el pdf

```
var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
{
    GlobalSettings = {
        ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
        Orientation = Orientation.Landscape,
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4Plus,
        HtmlContent = TemplateReporteRentals.GetHTMLString();
    },
    Objects = {
        new ObjectSettings() {
            PagesCount = true,
            HtmlContent = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In consectetur mauris eget ultrices  iaculis. Ut                               odio viverra, molestie lectus nec, venenatis turpis.",
            WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8" },
            HeaderSettings = { FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]", Line = true, Spacing = 2.812 }
        }
    }
};
```

**Genero el html**

```
public static string GetHTMLString()
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
    
                sb.Append(@" 
                            
                      foreach (var item in caja.models)
                           {
                                    <table style='border-collapse:collapse' width='100%' border='1'......
                            }
                 ");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como observan en la imagen , el contenido sale cortado y por este metodo de rotativa no veo la forma de que esto no suceda , ya que al enviar la informacion no se cuantas filas tendre

**Pregunta**

Existe alguna manera de controlar cuando se corte el contenido final del pdf? o existe alguna otra libreria que me sea posible realizarlo?
Estoy investigando desde varios dias atras , porfavor leo sus sugerencias
Gracias

Answer (score 2):

puedes crear clases `Css` en la que luego aplicas a tu Html. Por ejemplo

```
.keep-together {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.break-before {
    page-break-before: always;
}

.break-after {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

Luego en tu Html puedes hacer algo parecido a esto

```
<p>Page 1, paragraph 1</p>
<p class="break-before">Page 2, paragraph 1</p>
<p>Page 2, paragraph 2</p>
```

Puedes consultar más sobre los `Paged Media` en [Paged Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media)

Comment: seria una parte de la solución , pero como mencione en mi pregunta , los datos son dinámicos, no se de que tamaño tendré la tabla , por lo tanto no sabre donde poner los saltos de pagina

Comment: Tenía el problema de que el corte de pagina se me generaba justo en el centro de una línea de texto, usé la clase break-before dentro de un ciclo que cuenta las lineas de mi tabla para generar el punto de quiebre en la línea deseada. Agradecido.